# Is there enough information in a given quantum state to determine the state beforehand?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem, determinism

If I knew all the information about a state, and I knew the laws of physics in their complete totality, could I "reverse engineer" it to find, with 100% certainty, the state before it?

Comment: Which state? A state of a statistical ensemble? A quantum state? The mechanical state of an object? The electromagnetic state of a system of charges/fields?

Comment: Quantum state.****

Comment: To this exactly refers the answer that I posted.

Answer (score 2):

This is another way of asking if the laws of physics are reversible.

In principle this is true in classical and quantum mechanics. This is just the consequence of microscopic reversibility of physical laws in these theories. In classical mechanics this is guaranteed by Liouville Theorem and in Quantum Mechanics by the unitarity of time evolution. This is true even for quantum measurements if you take the current state to be the superposition of all alternative "worlds" in the Everett interpretation.

Of course this is only a theoretical possibility. In practice one does not know all the information in a system, and even if one did the dynamics at that level can easily be too complex to compute.

However, this may not be true for quantum gravity. This is what the black hole information paradox and all the fun with firewalls is about.

---

@Sofia This is a mathematical device.
You can not physically interact with the other "world",
but you can use them in calculations.
It is a purely philosophical question if the other worlds are real.

Suppose the experiment starts some binary observable
in a superposition state, a measuring device in the ready state,
and an observer who has not seen the result.
When the measurement is performed
you get entagled that is a suoerposition of 
the observable in the 0 state, the measuring device showing "0", and an observer who has seen the "0"
and similarly for 1.
This superposition state can be rolled back in time,
but not the individual components

Of course an observer only experiences one of alternatives,
but in the Everett interpretation there is a complementary version
of the observer that experienced the alternative outcome.
Un(?)fortunately there is now way for the two versions of the observer
to have a beer and compare notes.

In this view there is no measurement problem.
Measurement is just the process of the observer becoming entangled with the experiment. In this view Schroedinger's cat really is both dead and alive,
and when you open the box you seen both a live and a dead cat.

Comment: Given the result of a measurement how do you collect the information from the alternative worlds, in order to estimate the pre-measurement state?

Answer (score 0):

In the quantum theory, given the state of a system after a certain measurement, you cannot know what was the state before the measurement because the measurement is not a 1 to 1 process, it is a many to 1 process. Different states before a measurement can lead to the same state after measurement.

Only deterministic processes that produce a 1 to 1 transformation, not many to 1, allow you such predictions.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have $100$ % knowledge of the current state, bc you have ignored the observer state and the environment.